# CSS DIV Tag fills first view but doesnt strech with content

Tags: html, css, layout

I have page with a header, left and right content and a footer.  I have the left side bar to fill the first screen but then when the content in the right causes a need for a scroll bar the left sidebar does not extend down.  I have tried min and max height and setting the overflow to hidden, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background:#FFF;
  margin:0px;
}   
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto auto;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
#header {
  height: 55px;
  padding:  0 14px ;
}
#navigation {
 background:#a4c2c2;
 color: #990000;
}
#navigation a {
  font:10px arial;
  color: #285151;
  text-decoration:none;
  letter-spacing:0.1em;
  height:15px;
}   
#navigation a:hover {
  color: #285151;
  background-color: #D9E6E6;
  height: 15px;
  background-position: center center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
#sidebar {
  background:#a4c2c2;
  width:231px;
  font:12px georgia;
  color: #336666;
  line-height:18px;
  float:left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:-1;   
  height:100%;
  min-height:auto;
}
#sidebar div {
 height:2000px;
}
#rightside {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:231px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 25px;
}
#maincontent {
  background:#fff;
  font:11px arial;
  line-height:20px;
  color:#333333;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-align:justify;
}
#footer {
  background:#999966;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  padding-left: 231px;
  font:11px arial;
  line-height:20px;
  color:#333333;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header" class="logo">
  Header Content
  </div>

  <div id="navigation" height="36">
  Navigation Information
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar" height=100%>
  Left side content
  </div>

  <div id="rightside">
  Page Content
  </div>

  <br class="clearfloat" /> 

  <div id="footer">
   Footer information
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example / reduced test case of your code, preferably with a code snippet or a JSFiddle. Also, would be helpful if you can provide some illustration/mockup on your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a container for the sidebar AND the content. I call it ".content_container":

```
<div class="content_container">    
<div id="sidebar"> Left side content </div>
<div id="rightside"> Page Content </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.content_container {
border:2px solid red;
overflow: auto;
height:100%;
}
```

In this way, when the content on the right goes down, the height of the sidebar follows it.

http://jsfiddle.net/5xko3yen/1/

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.   I have another issue and I think it is still from my original code.   For some reason the sidebar tags are creating a scroll bar with about 5 extra lines even though there is no content to create the need. Any suggestions how to correct that?

Comment: because you are using `position:absolute;`. 100% height with absolute positioning means the total height of the screen. I suggest to use `position: relative;`.

If you want to keep that absolute positioning, add the line `margin-bottom:-75px;` to `#sidebar`. -75px means that you are subtracting the height of the header and borders.

Comment: I left position:absolute; and added margin-bottom:-75px; but the page still extends to the 2000px of the #sidebar div height:2000px;.    I also tried to change to position: relative; but the sidebard cut off after the content and did not extend even to the first screen.  I am really at a loss.

Comment: why do you need for that 2000px div? 

it seems ok, or I don't understand what are you looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/prkx1fnv/1/

Comment: See when the page content is longer than the side bar, the sidebar does not extend down to match. http://jsfiddle.net/prkx1fnv/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to place left and right div inside one container div. Modify Above code with below content, 100% it works.

Add this in CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  background:#a4c2c2;
  width:231px;
  font:12px georgia;
  color: #336666;
  line-height:18px;
  float:left;
  position: absolute;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
  z-index:-1;   
  /*height:100%;*/
  min-height:auto;
}
```

Comment sidebar and rightside div and add

```
<div class="sidebar">
<div class="sidebar">Left side content</div>
<div id="rightside">Page Content</div>
</div>
```